# information lost in citations using {biblatex}

Tags: biblatex

I used `\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=2,]{biblatex}` to make my citations into authoryear instead of numbers, it works. But then all extra information in the citation disappears: for example "Theorem 1.1" will not show up if I write `\cite[Theorem 1.1]{Kis06}`. I only have a [Kis06] as follows in the picture:

[image]

while what I want is [Kin06, Theorem 1.1]

I set the references by hand without using .bib, for example:

```
\bibitem[Kis06]{Kis06}
        M. Kisin, Crystalline representations and $F$-crystals, in Algebraic Geometry and Number Theory, Drinfeld 50th Birthday volume, Progress in Mathematics \textbf{253}, Birkh\"auser, (2006), p.459-496.
```

more information on my packages:

```
\documentclass[10 pt, singlespacing, headsepline]{book}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, enumerate, amsfonts, stmaryrd, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, comment, todonotes, mathrsfs, mathtools}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage[toc,page,title,titletoc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor, color}
\usepackage[all,color]{xy}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=2,]{biblatex}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
```

Extral question: Is it possible to modify the character "Kis06" (for example as in the picture above): it is too big and bold...

Thank you for any remarks!

---

MODIFIED (NEW) QUESTION:

---

I realize, as pointed in the comments by
@Joseph Wright, to keep `\bibitem` I should use `\natbib`. So I modified my usepackage as follows

```
\documentclass[10 pt, singlespacing, headsepline]{book}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % I add here
%\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd, enumerate, amsfonts, stmaryrd, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, comment, todonotes, mathrsfs, mathtools}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage[toc,page,title,titletoc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor, color}
\usepackage[all,color]{xy}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=2,]{biblatex} % I canceled this
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
```

When I compile, the error is shown as

> "File `natbib.sty' not found. \usepackage"

Ps. I use Texstudio on my laptop, strange thing is that when I copy the same usepackages (with some short minimum context with `\cite[]{}`) to test online on website "overleaf", it works... but on my Texstudio it crashes... Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Text.SE. Please do not post pictures of code, but the code itself.

Comment: Thank you, I will modify it.

Comment: `\bibitem[Kis06]{Kis06}` is `natbib` syntax, not `biblatex` - did you set things up manually in your `,bbl` file?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the modification ! @Roland

Comment: Actually I didn't use .bib (it always index the citation with numbers, no matter what style I use), I set manually all the references with \bibitem.  I see maybe I should use \natbib, the problem is that it can not compile (conflicts with some package?) if I, for example cancel package {biblatex} and use package {natbib}. @Joseph Wright Thank you for any remarks.

Comment: Using a manually-created `.bbl` with `biblatex` is possible but would be a _lot_ of work, as it's a version of the entire database. I think we could do with an edit showing the issue you actually want to solve: why can't you use `natbib`/why can't you use ` .bib` file.

Comment: @Joseph Wright Thanks again for the patience and practical suggestion, I hence modified the question to try to find a way to make `natbib` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) [writes in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630571/information-lost-in-citations-using-biblatex#comment1572495_630571), you cannot use a manual bibliography written with `\bibitem`s together with `biblatex`. If you write your `thebibliography` environment yourself, you can only use it together with bibliography and citation packages that are based on the standard LaTeX approach to bibliographies.

Joseph suggests to use `natbib` instead and indeed `natbib` is one of the most popular `thebibliography`-based citation/bibliography packages.

Get rid of `\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=2,]{biblatex}` and add something like

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

In the edit it is suggested that you get an error when you try to use `natbib` on your local machine. The error quoted in the edit, just says that `natbib` could not be found. So the first thing to check is if `natbib` is installed. While it is usually recommended to install a full TeX distribution, not everyone does that, in which case you may have to install additional packages when you need them. If and how that is possible depends on the way you installed TeX on your system.

- With MikTeX you can use the on-the-fly installation feature or the MikTeX Console.
- With a TeX live installed directly from TUG you would use `tlmgr`.
- With a TeX live installed via your Linux distribution's package manager, you have to identify the relevant package (in Debian `natbib` seems to live in `texlive-latex-base`, so it should normally already be there).

The following simplified MWE should compile without a problem

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \citep{Kis06}

\begin{thebibliography}{Kis06}
  \bibitem[Kis06]{Kis06}
    M. Kisin,
    Crystalline representations and $F$-crystals,
    in Algebraic Geometry and Number Theory,
    Drinfeld 50th~Birthday volume,
    Progress in Mathematics \textbf{253},
    Birkh\"auser, (2006), p.459-496.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

In your current setup, however, you can't really most of `natbib`'s advanced features (`\citep`/`\citet`) anyway, since you would have to pass author names and publication year to `natbib` via the optional argument of `\bibitem`. What's more `natbib` does not officially support "alphabetic" citation styles, so you might as well drop `natbib` completely and work with LaTeX's standard definitions (or with `\usepackage{cite}`)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{Kis06}

\begin{thebibliography}{Kis06}
  \bibitem[Kis06]{Kis06}
    M. Kisin,
    Crystalline representations and $F$-crystals,
    in Algebraic Geometry and Number Theory,
    Drinfeld 50th~Birthday volume,
    Progress in Mathematics \textbf{253},
    Birkh\"auser, (2006), p.459-496.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see why online latex works better now. Thank you for the detailed answer, I will try your suggestions. @moewe (which also indicates maybe it's better to work online and preserve all tex files in Cloud...)