# "Citation X on page X undefined on input line X" error with super minimal example

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I'm getting a `Citation 'test' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.` error for the below example on Overleaf.

I've looked at many other questions and I can't find the error. Any ideas?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{test} bibtest
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load `biblatex`, if you use a manual `thebibliography` environment to make your bibliography.

Comment: I agree that https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630571/35864 is basically the same problem, but the question here is so much clearer (with a much better MWE) that it might be better to leave this one here open.

Comment: I agree with @moewe that this question is more clear. I suggest we close the older question as a duplicate of this one. Maybe moewe as a gold badge holder could do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` requires another data format with`\refsection`, `\datalist`, `\entry` and `\field` etc., but not a `thebibliography` environment with `\bibitem`. So loading package `biblatex` but using a `thebibliography` environment — either manually edited or created by `bibtex` with another document — does not work.

In other words: You cannot mix the package with a manually created `thebibliography` environment.  Instead you should use a `bib` file and run `biber`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Test: \cite{aksin}, \autocite{aksin}, \parencite{aksin}, \footcite{aksin} (the last one is nonsense with the default cite style, but could be useful, e.g., with \texttt{cite=authoryear} option).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

or manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{test} bibtest
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

If you are interesting in converting an already existing `thebibliography` environment into a `bib` file, see: [Convert from a textplain reference to bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233442/277964).

Answer (score 0):

As caboah told you, your MWE works without `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{test} bibtest
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you would like to use `biblatex`, you have to create a `.bib` file, for example `mybib.bib`:

```
@article{test,
    title={This is a test},
    author={Paulinho, van Duck},
    journal={Quack University Journal},
    volume={10},
    pages={16--30},
    date={2023-03-11},
    url={https://www.quackforyou.com}
}
```

and then add it to your document with `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]